# HTTP outbound gateway - uri variable - encoding

Tags: spring, spring-integration, gateway, outbound

I have a http outbound gateway, which requires substitutions via uri-variable. I am sending a String payload

```
<int-http:outbound-gateway  
               url="https://ia-zatie.str13.tst.bnst.nh/ia-zaatie/rest/signan/v2/wg/{workgroupId}//actionType/New?max={maxCount}"
               http-method="GET" 
               header-mapper="headerMapper"
               expected-response-type="java.lang.String" request-factory="sslFactory" >
               <int-http:uri-variable name="workgroupId" expression="payload['workgroupId']" />
               <int-http:uri-variable name="maxCount" expression="payload['maxCount']"/>
        </int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

Payload - { "workgroupId":"BTL_IT", "maxCount":1}

> nested exception is
>   org.springframework.expression.spel.SpelEvaluationException: EL1001E:
>   Type conversion problem, cannot convert from java.lang.String to
>   java.lang.Integer
>           at
>   org.springframework.integration.http.outbound.HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(HttpRequestExecutingMessageHandler.java:409)

<strike>Why it is assuming the value of workgroupId to be an Integer? please can you tell how to solve this.</strike>

**EDIT:**
I now changed code to concatenate at controller level and pass payload as required for the dynamic part.
The new problem is "?" becoming %3F like - /New%3Fmax=1.
How can I encode and where?

```
> <int-http:outbound-gateway    
>                  url="https://ia-zatie.str13.tst.bnst.nh/ia-zaatie/rest/signan/v2/wg/{workgroup}"
>                  http-method="GET" 
>                  header-mapper="headerMapper"
>                  expected-response-type="java.lang.String" request-factory="sslFactory" >
>              <int-http:uri-variable name="workgroup" expression="payload" />
>                       </int-http:outbound-gateway>
```

Payload:

```
String payload = gsRequest.getWorkgroup()+"/actionType/New?max="+ gsRequest.getMaxCount();
which is like - BL_IH/actionType/New?max=1
```

Comment: I am guessing now, but maybe the problem is with maxcount and not with workgroup?

Comment: @Reg. nope. I clearly see it is with workgroup. I see the post http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/integration/121099-http-outbond-gateway-with-post-and-uri-variable-in-url. We use JMS hence facing problem with conversion for header fields with hyphen. otherwise I can use payload.getWorkgroup**() etc

Comment: What version of Spring Integration are you using? I am having trouble finding a version with relevant code on line 409. Can you also edit the question to show the full stack trace?

Comment: Yes, please, full stack-trace into the studio!

Comment: I understand you want to help, but the issue is expression on payload is looking for index number like 0,1,.. when I passed payload[0], I could see, the request getting %7B. which is {. first charcter in payload. What I am lookig for is - a way to extract values from JSON String payload. If I use transformer, I am getting errors because we use JMS and some header parts have hyphen and it is complaining. Is there a way to transform only payload? like <int:json-to-object-transformer input-channel="objectMapperInput"
    type="foo.MyDomainObject"/>. Version 1.4.3 boot nd spring integration 4.3.6

Comment: ok. used - encode-uri="false". Thuis question can be closed.